# SQL Server error creating a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to re-create a foreign key constraint that got deleted recently and SQL Server is not letting me. Here's the DDL that SQL Server Management Studio gave me:

```
/* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.CleansingOperations SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.CleansedData ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_CleansedData_CleansingOperations FOREIGN KEY
    (
    CleansedOperationID
    ) REFERENCES dbo.CleansingOperations
    (
    CleansingOperationID
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.CleansedData SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

and here is the error that I get when I run it:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CleansedData_CleansingOperations". The conflict occurred in database "NetVis203", table "dbo.CleansingOperations", column 'CleansingOperationID'.
>
> Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

What does it all mean? As far as I can see, it is saying that the constraint is 'conflicting' with itself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that there's a row in CleansedData that doesn't have a corresponding row in CleansingOperations

```
SELECT CleansingOperationId FROM dbo.CleansedData
EXCEPT
SELECT CleansingOperationId FROM dbo.CleansingOperations
```

should return no rows for your statement to work.

There's a NOCHECK keyword, which gets around the error, but better to understand what rows would violate the foreign key.

The reason for the error message, is that SQL Server imagines the foreign key is in place and then asserts that all rows satisfy the constraint before committing the statement. The reason for the second error message has to do with error handling (which I can never get right either).

Comment: Excellent, that's explained it to me and given me enough to fix it. Cheers.